# Angular 4 FormGroup value match array item

Tags: angular

I want to create a custom validation function for my form group which validates the input of the country matches to my country list item.

This is my country list:

```
this.sharedService.getCountry().subscribe(res => {
  res.map(item => {
    this.countryList.push(item);
  });
});
```

my form is:

```
this.form = fb.group({
    country: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write a custom validator service which checks for the input as follows,

```
function check_if_valid(value,array){
   if((alue){ 
       const isInArray = array.includes(value);
       return true;
   } else {
       return false;
   }
}

@Injectable()
export class ValidatorsService {

   public isInteger = (control:FormControl) => {
        return check_if_valid(control.value,yourarray);
   }

}
```

and in component

```
constructor(private _ValidatorsService: ValidatorsService){
    }

country: new FormControl('', [Validators.required,this._ValidatorsService.isInteger ]),
```

Comment: so how do I call my array?

Comment: can I call it in constructor() ?

Comment: you can make the api call in service itself unless you are not using in your component

Comment: I get the error when I write this._ValidatorsService.isInteger in formControl

Comment: TS2345:Argument of type '(((control: AbstractControl) => ValidationErrors) | ((control: FormControl) => boolean))[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ValidatorFn | ValidatorFn[] | AbstractControlOptions'. Type '(((control: AbstractControl) => ValidationErrors) | ((control: FormControl) => boolean))[]' has no properties in common with type 'AbstractControlOptions'.